Amplitude of superposition of forces
Find the amplitude of forces of superposition of 300cos13πt, 500sin6.4 πt + 300sin 13πt +600cos 18.8 πt
My answer is sqrt((300^2)+300^2) = 424 after superimposing both cos13πt and sin13πt, After which, the overall of amplitude of superimposed of all 4 forces are sqrt( (434^2)+ (500^2) + (600^2)) = 893, correct me if I am wrong

Yes, you are correct. You made a small error, misstyping 424, 434, and that threw your answer off a bit!

@kamran, so the final answer would be sqrt( (424^2)+ (500^2) + (600^2)) = 889, am i right ?

yes, right.  just buffer.11111
